# Patient age is not displayed correctly

Tags: api, openfda

Patient Age is displayed as below:

Patient Age 19710 DA

using the below URL:
https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfmaude/detail.cfm?mdrfoi__id=16232230&pc=CCK&device_sequence_no=1

and API URL as well:

[https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?api_key=MyAPIKey&search=date_received:[20213005+TO+20231005]AND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22IOL%22&limit=1000](https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?api_key=MyAPIKey&search=date_received:%5B20213005+TO+20231005%5DAND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22IOL%22&limit=1000)

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

the data view in Accessdata and openFDA are no always in perfect sync, as different processing affects the data in both places. The difference here seems to be that Accessdata is displaying patient_age in the units days alive, while openFDA is using years. There doesn't appear to be any discrepancy in the actual data, just a greater degree of granularity in the Accessdata format.

Regards,

Violet Wren,

openFDA Tech Lead

Comment: Hi Wren, are there any chances in future patient age will be formatted in the response?

Comment: We don't have current plans to make a change to format, but it's always possible that changes can occur in the future.